# Different Abilities, One Column

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a small CRUD application for some cards.  Now part of my application will be using checkboxes to select cards based on their ability.  This has gone great so far when a card only has one ability.  But when there's a card has two abilities, this is where I get lost.

I can only put one ability in one column in my table.  So when I check the 'Convoke' checkbox, it comes back with cards that have Convoke.  But I'm not sure how I can search a card that has two different abilities, as I can't fit two abilities in one column.

Here's my code for a singular checkbox:

```
<html>
<title>MySQL Search!</title>
<body>
<p>Search Results:</p>
<table width="600" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<th>Card Name</th>
<th>Mana Cost</th>
<th>Card Set</th>
<th>Ability</th>
<th>Image</th>
</tr>
<?php
require 'dbconnect.php';
$Checkbox = $_POST['Ability'];
$q="SELECT * FROM mtgcards WHERE Ability LIKE '%$Checkbox%'";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
        Echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
    Echo "<td>" . $row['Mana Cost'] . "</td>";
    Echo "<td>" . $row['Colour'] . "</td>";
    Echo "<td>" . $row['Set'] . "</td>";
        Echo "<td>" . $row['Ability'] . "</td>";
        Echo "<td>" . '<img style="display:block" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['Image']) . '" width="100%" height="100%" /></td>';
        Echo "</tr>";
}

mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
</html>
</body>
```

I'm really bad at articulating over a keyboard, so if you're not sure what I'm asking, just ask me to clarify it.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you need to add a child table that has many to one relationship to allow you to have multiple abilities attached to a single card. Then do an inner join on select. I can expand if you post your create sql for the parent table.

Comment: What do you mean my create sql?  I'm sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: create sql for mtgcards table

Comment: I'm sorry, I never created it myself, per se.  I used Workbench and just filled in the GUI.

Comment: Then create a second table that has a foreign key to the first table and allows you to enter multiple abilities/records tied to one record in the main table. Here's my favorite JOINs reference: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Your HTML is horrid and may be part of the problem. You should [validate your HTML](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) before proceeding here.